# Cypress: How to identify if element contains only numbers

Tags: cypress

please how to identify in cypress, if element contains only numbers? I have a div which contains some dynamic data and I would like to see to fail the test, if the data will contain anything but numbers. Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `Number.isNaN(+value)` is easier than using a regex,

```js
cy.get('input')
  .type('123')
  .invoke('val')
  .should(value => {
    expect(Number.isNaN(+value), 'input should be a number').to.eq(false)    // passes
  })

cy.get('input')
  .type('123.45')
  .invoke('val')
  .should(value => {
    expect(Number.isNaN(+value), 'input should be a number').to.eq(false)    // passes
  })

cy.get('input')
  .type('abc')
  .invoke('val')
  .should(value => {
    expect(Number.isNaN(+value), 'input should be a number').to.eq(false)    // fails
  })
```

or for strictly **integer** numbers

```js
cy.get('input')
  .type('123')
  .invoke('val')
  .should(value => {
    expect(Number.isInteger(+value), 'input should be an integer').to.eq(true) // passes
  })

cy.get('input')
  .type('123.45')
  .invoke('val')
  .should(value => {
    expect(Number.isInteger(+value), 'input should be an integer').to.eq(true) // fails
  })

cy.get('input')
  .type('abc')
  .invoke('val')
  .should(value => {
    expect(Number.isInteger(+value), 'input should be an integer').to.eq(true) // fails
  })
```

Comment: I prefer your second solution, because the first is clumsy with false+false= true.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `match()` and then compare it with a regex. The `/^[0-9]*$/` regex value will only check for numbers.

```
cy.get('#greeting')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('match', /^[0-9]*$/)
```

Thanks, @Prabhu Mohan for this. If you are checking the numbers that contain decimals, you can use -

```
cy.get('#greeting')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('match', /^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/)
```

Comment: The regex does not handle numbers with a decimal point.

Comment: I wonder what would be the correct regex then?

Comment: @NankerPhelge try this regex it will handle both decimal numbers and including digits /^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/ practice here https://regexr.com/

Comment: @PrabhuMohan Thanks for the regex, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using regular expression. Refer for an idea https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Regular-Expression